# openpyxl how to highlight all other columns that differ if column A is same?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have one excel file that contains multiple columns. First column contains the key and there are duplicates.

What I want to achieve is to compare values in all columns that contain same key, and highlight if they differ.

Below is an example:

```
values = {'product_key': [101, 102, 103, 101, 105, 103],
        'date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-05-05', '2019-11-15', '2020-03-02', '2019-03-01', '2019-11-15'],
        'price': ['$15', '$13', '$11', '$14',' $20', '$18']}
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = ['product_key', 'date', 'price'])
```

And my table look like this:

```
   product_key  date      price
      101    2020-01-01   $15
      102    2020-05-05   $13
      103    2019-11-15   $11
      101    2020-03-02   $14
      105    2019-03-01   $20
      103    2019-11-15   $18
```

I want to have the two price and date of 101 highlighted, and the price of 103 highlighted. I'm currently using openpyxl. And if openpyxl cannot do that, is there any other library (available in anaconda) can help?

Comment: The easiest thing would be to add conditional formatting for the relevant range. NB. openpyxl just acts as a conduit for this so you'll have to check the Excel docs for this and possibly look at the relevant source files to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 1):

I did not attempt to achieve this with only `openpyxl`, but that will require you to iterate over the entire sheet (=dataframe) and manually grouping by each `product_key` then compare using `openpyxl`/"Excel" syntax.

Using [`styleframe`](https://pypi.org/project/styleframe/) (of which I'm one of the maintainers) will allow you to solve this on the dataframe level, using pandas syntax.

First we group by the `product_key` then using `.apply` to call a custom function on each sub dataframe. Then we can use `duplicated` with negation (`~`) and style using `styleframe`.

```
from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler

values = {'product_key': [101, 102, 103, 101, 105, 103],
          'date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-05-05', '2019-11-15', '2020-03-02', '2019-03-01', '2019-11-15'],
          'price': ['$15', '$13', '$11', '$14',' $20', '$18']}
full_df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['product_key', 'date', 'price'])

yellow_bg_style = Styler(bg_color='yellow')
full_sf = StyleFrame(full_df)

def style_non_matching(grouped_df):
    if len(grouped_df) == 1:
        return
    grouped_sf = StyleFrame(grouped_df)
    for column in ('date', 'price'):
        grouped_sf.apply_style_by_indexes(grouped_sf[~grouped_sf[column].duplicated(keep=False)],
                                          yellow_bg_style,
                                          cols_to_style=column)

full_sf.groupby('product_key').apply(style_non_matching)
full_sf.to_excel('test.xlsx').save()
```

Will produce

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer! however im only allowed  to use library available in anaconda. I do not see styleframe in Anaconda. is there any alternative?

Comment: @CCCCos Since you are not the first (and probably not the last) I'll investigate what it takes to make styleframe availble on Anaconda

Comment: @CCCCos BTW, you can install `styleframe` on `conda` using `pip`: 1. activate the conda environment, 2. `conda install pip`, 3. `pip install styleframe`, 4. `conda list` should show `styleframe`